# How to link the external .lib into the Fortran

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran, intel-parallel-studio

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8aV8.png)

I am trying to recompile a Fortran projects using Intel Visual Fortran (Parallel Studio XE 2017) with MS Visual Studio 2013. The code uses a couple of external .lib files in the Fortran script which are:-

```
use m21df
use Mzcalendar
```

I have the .lib with me, but i am having problem to link them. When i compile the project, it gave me `error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file. Check INCLUDE paths`.

What can I do to fix this problem whereby make my script recognizes the .lib files?

Comment: Please do *not* enter important information like the code or error messages as screenshots and pictures. Also, use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. The same holds for the `visual-studio` tag. Do not just use the specific version tags, use those only when necessary. Tags are **extremely** important here at Stack Overflow. Without correct tags people won't read your question.

Comment: Do the .mod files exist for these libraries?  Are they on the include path?

Comment: Hi @VladimirF, sorry about that, i am new to Stack Overflow. Note taken on that.

Comment: Hi @cup , i do not have the .mod files, but only the .lib files. Could i generate the .mod files myself with the .lib? or i have to get the .mod files from the author?

Comment: The author should have supplied both the lib and mod files.  You can always generate them as a stop gap while waiting for the ones from the author.

Comment: Hi @cup, thanks for the reply. For the .lib files, i do not have the codes, only .lib files are provided. In this case, can i still generate the .mod?

Comment: If you have the source code. But best is to ask the provider of the lib what you should do.

Comment: @VladimirF, noted with thanks.